# Strategy to maintain dotfiles for different OSs (i.e. osx and ubuntu)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, git, zsh, dotfiles

I use a Git repository to maintain my dotfiles (vimrc, zshrc, tmux.conf, etc.). As I've two different operating systems (OSX at home and Ubuntu at work) I've dedicated a branch for each system. This results in different versions of dotfiles as OSs are not used to use the same tools/libraries to do a job. This makes the maintenance of dotfiles hard for all the branches (diverged dotfiles). I was thinking if there could be a better strategy for this. Maybe to include system specific dotfiles in another file and include them in dotfiles.

In other words, I'm looking for a cross-platform strategy for maintaining dotfiles for computers with different OS.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/serialoverflow/dotfiles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For shell scripts like .zshrc you can use an environment variable or the answer to some command like uname. But for non-shell dotfiles like .vimrc you should do the manual work of commiting patches from one branch to another (from one OS to another).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Envite's answer: I use one common `.zshrc` file, where all ,,portable'' stuff (like shell function definitions etc.) is included. Additionally, I have an extra file `.zshrc-MACHINE_A` etc. for every computer where I'm using the shared config. Here I define e.g. the `PATH`, some alias reflecting the current installed programs and so on.

The last part of my common `.zshrc` file reads

```
# load $HOST specific setting

if [[ -f ~/.zshrc-$HOST ]]; then
   [[ ! -f ~/.zshrc-$HOST.zwc || ~/.zshrc-$HOST -nt ~/.zshrc-$HOST.zwc ]] && { zcompile ~/.zshrc-$HOST; print - compiled \~/.zshrc-$HOST. }
   source ~/.zshrc-$HOST
fi
```

According to `man zshparam` the parameter `$HOST` contains the current host name, hence should be portable and saves an external program call.
And every time the according `.zshrc-$HOST` file is changed it'll get compiled (via `zcompile`). The compilation serves the purpose of (I quote `man zshbuiltins`):

> (...) faster autoloading of functions and execution of scripts by avoiding
>                 parsing of the text when the files are read.

Probably nowadays you won't notice any difference(?), but it won't hurt either. Btw. the compiles `*.zwc` files are architecture dependent and cannot be exchanges between different systems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [best solution I've come across](http://web.archive.org/web/20150703225111/blog.alextercete.com/cross-platform-dotfiles/). I recommend clicking the link rather than reading about it here:

> ## THE IDEA
>
> I've adapted @holman's ideia of symlinking files whose filename ends with ".symlink", and instead I'm symlinking files whose filename matches the regular expression `\.(<os>-)?symlink$`. By doing that, I can have files that are always symlinked, and files that are symlinked just in a specific environment.
>
> For example, in my `~/.gitconfig` I include `~/.gitconfig_include`, which contains OS-specific configurations.
>
> ```
> [include]
>     path = ~/.gitconfig_include
> ```
>
> Then I have two .gitconfig_include files: one for Linux and another one for Windows.
>
> ```
> dotfiles
> |-- git
>     |-- .gitconfig.symlink
>     |-- .gitconfig_include.linux-symlink
>     |-- .gitconfig_include.windows-symlink
> ```
>
> This allows a symlink to have the same name, but different targets, depending on the OS.
>
> Unfortunatelly, this strategy wasn't enough to handle all the requirements for my cross-platform dotfiles.
>
> ### Vim's bad decision on Windows
>
> For some reason, Vim looks for its files in `~/vimfiles` instead of `~/.vim` on Windows. This means that, if I wanted to maintain the same strategy, I would have to duplicate the files folder—which I didn't want to do, for obvious reasons.
>
> ```
> dotfiles
> |-- vim
>     |-- .vim.linux-symlink
>     |-- vimfiles.windows-symlink
> ```
>
> Instead of duplicating the files folder, I've created a file matching the folder's name, with the ".symlinks" extension.
>
> ```
> dotfiles
> |-- vim
>     |-- .vim
>     |-- .vim.symlinks
> ```
>
> The .vim.symlinks file contains the symlink name for each environment.
>
> ```
> linux: .vim
> windows: vimfiles
> ```
>
> This allows a symlink to have different names, but the same target, depending on the OS.
>
> ## THE WORKING SOLUTION
>
> If you want to check how everything ended up, please visit my [dotfiles on GitHub](https://github.com/alextercete/dotfiles).

Comment: Cool that you copied the solution here, that link is dead now.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to have a separate repositories for each machine.

Since git doesn't follow symlinks (it just stores them), and [hard links don't work either](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/git-dotfiles-and-hardlinks/), I have written a script that contains a list of files that are the same on both machines. After I've made changes in one of the repositories, I run the script.

If it detects (my computing a checksum) that any of the shared files have changed in this repository, it copies them to the other repository. Then I change to that repository and commit the changes there are well.